# TYPO3 Best Way To Insert HTML on Subpages

Tags: typo3

first of all sorry for naming the title like this but I didn't find the right words to describe the situation...

I have a simple navigation with some navigation points and these have subpages and are displayed as dropdown. On some subpages I want to display content, especially these toggable pills (https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp) but I don't know if there is a better way than mine.

For now I created a content element for HTML and simply copy & paste the code from the link above in it. But if editors don't know HTML they could easily mix up my content element.

Another idea is that I could write the HTML in the template or create a fluid object and put it into a condition depending on the pageid. Maybe you can bring up a better idea for this case.

Comment: To better understand you: You want to have HTML (like e.g. FontAwesome icons with `<i class="fa fa-something"></i>` in your menu?

Comment: Not really, seems like I wrote it not clear. I have subpages and on some subpages I want to insert these bootstrap pills but I think inserting them as pure html in a content element isn't that good and so I am looking for a better way.

Comment: it is a navigation system? every pill/tab is a page? Or it is a tab system (that shows a different content for each tab/pill on the same page)?

Comment: Tabsystem with different content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: don't insert individual HTML by hand, use the appropriate content element

Your comments made clear you want a jump-navigation on some pages which targets the CEs (content elements) of that page.

This is available as menu-CE (depending on TYPO3 version: either a variant of the general menu-CE, or as one of the multiple menu-CEs).

What you need is to change the markup for this menu to the bootstrap pills markup. Depending on usage of CSC or FSC you have to modify typoscript or fluid templates.

Either you insert these CEs by hand on each page, or do it as part of the page layout, so there is a general menu in each page with this special layout.

- make a special content column (does not be a layout column), which inherits/gets it content from one central page
- create the menu by typoscript and fill a fluid variable with the menu
- use a viewhelper to get the menu (either PHP or typoscript)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think your answer is the help I needed. After reading your ideas I think I will do a fluid object with all needed wraps, write it in the template and create a simple ce with some text in it.